# В чем разница между JSON и JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Подскажите, пожалуйста, для чего нужен JSON и в чем его разница с JavaScript?

Comment: javascript язык при помощи которого в браузере все оживает. Так же есть nodejs, это такой же javascript, только для небраузера. А json это синтаксис, который разработан специально для конфигов. Вот например чтобы Вы увидели список всех своих друзей в соц сетях, браузерный javascript посылает запрос на сервер-nodejs. Последний выбирает из базы данных всю информацию и формирует конфиг, который в виде строки передается по интернету и попадает в браузер, где браузерный javascript, который чаще называют js (не путать с java, java это совершенно другой язык) отображает этот конфиг.

Answer (score 15):

JavaScript (/ˈdʒɑːvɑːˌskrɪpt/; аббр. JS) — прототипно-ориентированный сценарный **язык программирования**. Является реализацией языка ECMAScript (стандарт ECMA-262). https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) - **простой формат обмена данными**, удобный для чтения и написания как человеком, так и компьютером. Он основан на подмножестве языка программирования JavaScript, определенного в стандарте ECMA-262 3rd Edition - December 1999. JSON - текстовый формат, полностью независимый от языка реализации, но он использует соглашения, знакомые программистам C-подобных языков, таких как C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python и многих других. Эти свойства делают JSON идеальным языком обмена данными. http://json.org/json-ru.html

P.S. Поиск рулит ;)

Answer (score 10):

JS - это язык программирования.

JSON - это способ строковой записи объектов. Причем в такой форме, что если выполнить это представление как код на JS - вы получите сам объект.

Например, `"{ a : 1, b : 2}"` - это JSON-строка. Если выполнить ее как

```
var json = "{ a : 1, b : 2}";
var myobj = eval('(' + json + ')'); // или JSON.parse(json)
```

то практически выполняется код

```
var myobj = { a : 1, b : 2};
```

и получаете реальный объект, c myobj.a = 1 и myobj.a = 2.

Причем современные браузеры поддерживают еще и обратное преобразование, методом `JSON.stringify(myobj)`.

Т.е. для работы с JSON в JS не нужны специальные средства - достаточно просто выполнить строку. Что сделало его дико популярным при разработке frontend и при передаче данных между frontend и backend. До этого эту нишу занимал XML, и работа с ним на JS была диким мучением.

Comment: А как же `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @Qwertiy а про него упомянуто в ответе )

Comment: Ой.. Не заметил))

Answer (score 10):

Если имелась в виду разница в записи объекта в json'е и в js, то:

- В json все ключи должны быть в кавычках.
- В json ограничено количество типов значений: число, строка, bool и `null`. Больше никакие значения записать нельзя.
- В json строки надо заключать в двойные кавычки, а в js можно в одинарные.
- В json запрещена завершающая запятая.