# Преобразование JSON в "Пользовательский вид"

Tags: python, json, list

Получаю JSON такого вида:

```
{
    "one": "1",
    "two": [
        [1, 2, 3],
        ["1", "2", 3]
    ],
    "three": [
        [1, 2, 3],
        ["1", "2", 3]
    ]
}
```

Как достать данные из two, three в виде списка:

```
1 2 3 
1 2 3
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439183/178988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я плохо понял, в каком именно формате вы хотите получить данные, поэтому приведу несколько примеров:

```py
import json  # библиотека для работы с JSON


json_string = """
{
    "one": "1",
    "two": [
        [1, 2, 3],
        ["1", "2", 3]
    ],
    "three": [
        [1, 2, 3],
        ["1", "2", 3]
    ]
}
"""

parsed_string = json.loads(json_string)  # Создаём Python объект из JSON

print(parsed_string['two'])              # stdout: [[1, 2, 3], ['1', '2', 3]]

print(*parsed_string['two'])             # stdout: [1, 2, 3] ['1', '2', 3]

for x in parsed_string['two']:           # stdout: 1 2 3
    for n in x:                          #         1 2 3
        print(n, end=' ')
    print('')
```

Инструкция json.loads() возвращает Python словарь, поэтому Вы можете представить данные как Вам угодно.

Comment: Числа в массиве в кавычки запихивать было не обязательно. Кстати, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439183/178988 - по идее ответом будет парсер расширенного синтаксиса - под JS такой был, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло
А то я дальше вывода данных из 'two' в виде ['1', '2', '3'] ['1', '2', 3] не смог пройти
А не подскажите, как можно вывести в переменную конечный вид: 
1 2 3
1 2 3
Пробовал через .join, но выдает ошибку 'TypeError: can only join an iterable
'

Answer (score 0):

В общем сделал через pandas

```
import json  # библиотека для работы с JSON
import pandas as pd

json_string = """
{
    "one": "1",
    "two": [
        [1, 2, 3],
        ["1", "2", 3]
    ],
    "three": [
        [1, 2, 3],
        ["1", "2", 3]
    ]
}
"""

parsed_string = json.loads(json_string)  # Создаём Python объект из JSON



for x in parsed_string['two']:         
    xdf = pd.DataFrame(x)
    xdf1 = xdf.loc[0]
    xdf2 = xdf.loc[1]
    xdf3 = xdf.loc[2]
    xdf4 = pd.DataFrame({
    '1_columns': xdf1,
    '2_columns': xdf2,
    '3_columns': xdf3
    })
    print(xdf4)
```

Выводит это:

```
   1_columns   2_columns  3_columns
0  1           2          3
```

Правда не знаю, нормально ли это вообще все выглядит.

Не прочитал нормально документацию, только вчера(31.05) нашел в pandas read_json
Все работает как надо